# How do I declare and set the value of a DateTime object in different lexical scopes?

Tags: .net, datetime, lexical

I read on this question and answer, where you must create a new DateTime object if you need to modify (or shift) the time of the object, because DateTime is an immutable object type.

[Why DateTime.AddHours doesn't seem to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781420/why-datetime-addhours-doesnt-seem-to-work)

That's fine if the variable is being declared and a value is being set in the same lexical scope.  Except I'm declaring and setting the value in different lexical scope.  Normally I'd do "DateTime from_instant = null;" so it at least has a value, so I can use it after it's set.  However, with DateTime, once you set the value, it's immutable.  So how can I adjust the value of my object by doing "from_instant.AddHours(-10);" for example, outside the lexical scope it was declared in?

In my case below, whenever I reset "from_instant", it doesn't change.  I'd like to be able to change it.  How do you typically reset the value since it's immutable?

```
    DateTime from_instant = DateTime.Now;

    bool set_scan_start_instant_to_last_scan_instant = Convert.ToBoolean(GetConfig("set_scan_start_instant_to_last_scan_instant"));

    if (set_scan_start_instant_to_last_scan_instant)
    {
        from_instant = GetScanTimeFromFile(@".\last_scan_instant.txt");
        from_instant = DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scan_interval_minutes))
        {
            from_instant = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_minutes));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scan_interval_hours))
        {
            from_instant = DateTime.Now.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_hours));
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scan_interval_days))
        {
            from_instant = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_days));
        }
    }

    DateTime to_instant = DateTime.Now;
    WriteScanTimeToFile(@".\last_scan_instant.txt", to_instant.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("from_instant: " + from_instant.ToString());  
    Console.WriteLine("to_instant: " + to_instant.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you keep calling methods on `DateTime` and ignoring the return values. Don't do that.

Change this:

```
from_instant.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_hours));
```

to

```
from_instance = from_instant.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_hours));
```

Or:

```
fromInstance += TimeSpan.FromHours(Convert.ToInt32(scan_interval_hours));
```

(etc). It's not clear why you appear to think you can't do this. It's also not clear what you expect this code to do:

```
from_instant = GetScanTimeFromFile(@".\last_scan_instant.txt");
from_instant = DateTime.Now;
```

Why would you assign a value to `from_instant` and then immediately assign a different value?

(Side-note: underscores are pretty unidiomatic in C# code.)

> In my case below, whenever I reset "from_instant", it doesn't change.

Sounds like you're probably not diagnosing things properly. Changing the value of the variable really *will* change it...

Comment: Right, I understand that.  But you still need to set "from_instance" before the if/else because it won't be available after the if/else if you'd like to use the variable.  Where do I declare "from_instance" and how should I declare it?

Comment: @MacGyver: No, you don't need to set `from_instance` at all before the `if/else` if *every possible path* assigns it a value before it's read.

Comment: the double assignment was for troubleshooting... my concern was the  "use of unassigned local variable 'from_instance'" error when compiling in the Console.WriteLine("from_instant: " + from_instant.ToString());

Comment: @MacGyver: That's because in the `else` block, you don't assign a value to `from_instant` if all of `scan_interval_minutes`, `scan_interval_hours` and `scan_interval_days` are empty or null. If you include an unconditional `else` clause at the end of that set of `if / else if / ...` and assign some default value in there, it will compile with no problems.

Comment: for those reading, I changed "DateTime from_instant = DateTime.Now;" to just "DateTime from_instant;", and added an "else" clause where I set "from_instant = DateTime.Now;"