# Set a DateTime to 23:59:59

Tags: c#, datetime

can someone explain me why do this :

```
        public virtual ActionResult RecupererVehicules([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, String dateMin, String dateMax)
    {
        // Création des dates
        DateTime min = DateTime.Parse(dateMin);
        DateTime max = DateTime.Parse(dateMax);
        max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);

        return Json(Models.Vehicule.getVehiculesDates(min,max));
    }
```

Get me this :

> dateMin     "2016-06-26"
>   dateMax     "2016-07-06"
>   min         {26/06/2016 00:00:00}
>   max         {06/07/2016 00:00:00} <-- Why don't I have 23:59:59 ?

If someone have an answer, I'll be happy to ear it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you have to assign the value by

```
max = max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

instead of

```
max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

otherwise the correct date is being calculated but not assigned.

**Alternatively** you can also add this timespan by

```
.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

Comment: Actually if you want the last instant of a day (include milliseconds) and at the same time do only one operation...

DateTime.Today.AddTicks(TimeSpan.TicksPerDay - 1)

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is an **immutable `struct`**. So you cannot change the value of an instance of `DateTime`. If you add or substract something to a `DateTime` instance, you get a new instance with the resulting value in return.

So your line

```
max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

does not change `max`, but each `Add*` call returns a new `DateTime`. You will need to assign the resulting value to `max` again:

```
max = max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually assign the value to the `max` variable like this

```
max = max.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

Answer (score 0):

use DateTime.Add() method to add the time to the date.

```
DateTime date =  DateTime.Parse(dateMax);
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(36, 0, 0, 0);
```

> ```
> DateTime combined = date.Add(time);
> ```

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:dddd}", combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out how to fix this, but maybe you should exactly know what is going on and have an idea about the terminology.

The type `DateTime` is **immutable**. This means that once you initialize a `DateTime` variable to a value, you can never change it again.

All the methods on `DateTime` (eg. `AddDays`, `AddHours`, etc..) returns a new `DateTime`.

**This is the actual implementation for the Add method from Microsoft's Source:**

```
public DateTime AddTicks(long value) 
{
   long ticks = InternalTicks;
   return new DateTime((UInt64)(ticks + value) | InternalKind);
}
```

As others pointed out, you need to assign the returned value of your operations either to the same variable `max` or to another one:

```
max = max.Date.AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59).AddSeconds(59);
```

You would **better** use `max.Date` first in case the date sent was not set to midnight.