# Add hours to datetime in substring

Tags: powershell

I get a file with a list of timestamped values, that looks like this:

```
06/14/2018 1:00 1374
06/14/2018 2:00 1316
06/14/2018 3:00 1288
```

However I need to correct the time stamps by adding four hours to each row. I've been trying something like this:

```
...
$c = Get-Content $file |
     ForEach-Object { $_.[DateTime]$_.Substring(0, 15).AddHours(4) }
Set-Content $file -Value $c
```

But I get an error that string doesn't contain the method `AddHours`.

Comment: A quick search reveals this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781420/why-datetime-addhours-doesnt-seem-to-work
which might address the problem you're having: basically, you will need to create new DateTime object (instead of treating a string like DateTime)

Comment: `Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object { ([DateTime] $_.Substring(0,16)).AddHours(4) }`

Comment: It's unclear to me if the last four digits are tenthousands of a second. You may need to use `[datetime]:parseexact()` with a proper date time format descriptor and possibly a Globalization cultureinfo --> `[datetime]::parseexact("06/14/2018 1:00 1374","MM/dd/yyyy H:mm ffff",System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)`

Comment: First of all, wow! Thanks for prompt and thorough responses all. You all exceeded my expectations by a wide margin. I should have clarified that the last four digits are power consumption, and is the data that is being time stamped. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem is one of [*operator precedence*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Operator_Precedence):

```
 [datetime] $_.substring(0,15).addHours(4)
```

evaluates `$_.substring(0,15).addHours(4)` *before* applying the `[datetime]` cast, so `.addHours()` is called on a *string* instance rather than a `[datetime]` instance, resulting in the error you quote.

Use `(...)` to establish the desired precedence:

```
 ([datetime] $_.substring(0,15)).addHours(4)
```

---

Once the date arithmetic works, you need two additional pieces:

- format the recalculated dates the same way as the input dates
- append the remainder of the input line to the recalculated date

```
$lines = Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object{ 
  (([datetime] $_.substring(0,15)).addHours(4)).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy h:mm') +
    $_.substring(15)
} 

set-content $file -Value $lines
```

Note: Given that you're using a fixed prefix of 15 chars. from each line with only a single-digit hour and no AM/PM indicator, it is unclear how all 24 hours in a day would be handled.

Comment: I assumed that leaving off the last zero when the hours were two digits would be OK, like in Excel. I guess I will test and see. Or I could find the colon and add two digits I suppose. Thanks again!

Comment: @TeddyHeidemann: Look for a row that has a PM time stamp and see how that is represented, then we can adjust the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill says, you need to cast to `DateTime` before trying to call the `AddHours` method.

```
...
12 $c = Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object{([DateTime] $_.Substring(0,16)).AddHours(4)}
13 set-content $file -Value $c
```

Assuming you don't care about the remaining four digits on each line.

Comment: I do care about the last four digits, that's the power consumption. And I can't assume four digits because it could at some point be less.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this is what I have ended up with. It gives an error for the midnight reading but the end result is correct.

```
$c = Get-Content $file | ForEach-Object{(([datetime] $_.substring(0,15)).addHours(4)).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm') + $_.substring(15)} 
$c = $c -replace":000",":00"
set-content $file -Value $c'
```

Comment: What does the input time stamp for the midnight reading look like (or any PM value, for that matter)? Can't you just include one extra character, i.e. `$_.substring(0,15))` -> `$_.substring(0,16))`?